# Haskell - program hangs

Tags: haskell

I am now learning Haskell. As it is a purely functional language, which "everything is a value", I believe that I can compute whatever things I want, because "everything is a value"!

However, considering the following program which attempts to find the smallest integer tuple (a, b, c) satisfying the condition a^n + b^n == c^n given a user input n, which is a positive integer:

```
func :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer, Integer)
func n = head $ filter (\(a, b, c) -> a ^ n + b ^ n == c ^ n) listOfTuples

listOfTuplesWith :: Integer -> [(Integer, Integer, Integer)]
listOfTuplesWith 1 = [(1, 1, 1)]
listOfTuplesWith x = [(a, b, x) | a <- [1 .. x - 1], b <- [1 .. x - 1]] ++
    [(a, x, b) | a <- [1 .. x - 1], b <- [1 .. x]] ++
    [(x, a, b) | a <- [1 .. x], b <- [1 .. x]]

listOfTuples = concatMap listOfTuplesWith [1 .. ]

main = do
    line <- getLine
    print $ func $ read line
```

When I key in 2, the program outputs the expected value (3, 4, 5), however, when I key in 3, the program seems to hang forever. What's wrong with my program?

Comment: [Fermat's Last Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your program. It seems to hang forever because it *does* hang forever, because there are no such triples to find.

Comment: Your answer has no code. You should be able to prove this with just a few tens of thousands of pages of Coq, Agda, or Isabelle.

Comment: Does that mean in Haskell if the program specifies a value which does not exist it will hang forever?

Comment: @MichaelTsang After much deliberation and consultation with some friendly folks on IRC about how the heck to answer this question: "yes".

Comment: If the program specifies a computation that searches for a value that does not exist then that search will continue forever.